# Basic JSON PHP query trouble

Tags: php, html, json, last.fm

I've been trying (for a few days now) to display one item out of a JSON query, but because I'm terrible with the syntax and functions I'm failing...

My code looks as below

```
<p>I'm currently listening to

<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$string = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=matt1319&api_key=de676fee34a484f0c7ea2bd1c959d2d2&format=json&limit=1");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

echo *****;
?>
</p>
```

I want to get my most recently played song out of last.fm which is...

```
recenttracks.track[0].artist['#text'] (if I'm currently listening or..)     
recenttracks.track.artist['#text'] (If I'm not currently listening to a song)
```

Any help of pointing in the right direction would be great. As I'm fairly new to PHP (background in HTML) I'll be very grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` will serve up an array and should be represented as:

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=matt1319&api_key=de676fee34a484f0c7ea2bd1c959d2d2&format=json&limit=1");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

echo $json['recenttracks']['track'][0]['artist']['#text'];
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you so much, this has been killing me!